Как загрузить на сервер несколько файлов?
<input type="file" name="upfile[]" multiple>
<?php
            if (isset($_FILES["upfile"]["name"]) && @$_FILES["upfile"]["name"]!='') {
                $count_files = count($_FILES['upfile']['name']);
                for($img_count=1;$i<$count_files;$img_count++) {
                        $tmp_name   = $_FILES['upfile']["tmp_name"][$img_count];
                        $file       = 'picture'.$img_count.'.jpg';              
                        if (@move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/$file")){
                            $img_count++;
                        }
                }       
            }
?>

Пытаюсь загрузить на сайт несколько файлов в цикле, страница уходит в долгую загрузку, и потом вылетает по таймауту скрипта. Что я делаю не так? Спасибо!
UPD Причём, если убрать multiple, и грузить одну картинку без цикла, то всё нормально работает. В цикле же даже одна картинка не загружается.

Не надо использовать цикл for, особенно если вы не понимаете, как он работает. Для работы с массивами всегда используйте foreach

Проблема не с for. А с тем, кто его написал. Включите отображение ошибок РНР, и увидите.

И заодно уберите все @ из кода. Вы наверное не понимаете, что делает этот символ, а тупо скопировали его откуда-то. Так делать не надо.

Проще всего сделать загрузку нескольких файлов, если у каждого инпута будет уникальное имя. Например
<input type="file" name="file1">
<input type="file" name="file2">
<input type="file" name="file3">

В этом случае перебрать полученный массив можно простейшим циклом
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    // тут обрабатываем как единственный файл
    // Только обращаемся не к $_FILES['userfile'] используем $file
    // например $file['tmp_name'] и так далее
}

Но с точки зрения фронтенда удобнее когда у всех файлов одно и то же имя, например
<input type="file" name="upfile[]" multiple>

В этом случае каждый элемент массива $_FILES превращается в массив. И перебирать надо один из них, используя полученный индекс для обращения к остальным массивам
foreach($_FILES['upfile']['error'] as $i => $error) {
    if ($error !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       // сделать что-то ужасное
       die;
    }
    $tmp_name  = $_FILES['upfile']["tmp_name"][$i];
    $orig_name = $_FILES['upfile']["name"][$i];
    $file      = 'picture'.$img_count.'.jpg';              
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/$file");
}    

Если файлы вообще не загружаются, то проверить значения настроек
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size


спасибо, так работает. Но всё же - в чём проблема была с for?

@Jour что именно "всё"? Проблема там именно в for. Глушение ошибок плохо, но к исходной проблеме оно не имеет отношения.

@Jour никакой иронии. Я понятия не имею, о чем вы говорите. Вопрос был "почему не работает данный код", а не "всё ли в нём плохо". Вы не поняли, почему он не работает, хотя это очевидно, там тупейшая алгоритмическая ошибка. И решили просто попричитать о том что "всё плохо".
